# lp.transport , I want to prcess alot of cost matrices

Tags: r

I have 1000 cost matrices to process in lp.transport
They are 14x8 in size
I want to process all and get back results
of course I could write 1000 lines of code and specify different matrix each time but that is not good
I cant get lp.transport to handle dynamic variable name for the cost.mat argument

Help needed thanks

I have tried to use loops and send it dynamic variable name i.e I have 1000 matrice called
new =matrix_1 ....1000

I tried using a loop 1:1000 using a variable say x
and send it matrix_X, it does not like this or I am doing it wrong

Comment: It seems that you could place your matrices into a list and then use `lapply` with `lp.transport` as your anonymous function.  That will return a list of solutions for every matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make a loop that creates dynamic names, you should be able to also put the function in the function. Just put the lp.transport together in the loop where you make the variable name I would say.

Note: if you can provide some code, this might be easier to answer as well.

Comment: Hi Yes I could try that , I will have a go, if you could share some code where the cost.mat is being passed dynamically would be great I under pressure

Comment: Just thinking if I do that will lp.transport keep overwriting its own results as I go from matrix to matrix and I just end up with the result for matrix 1000

Answer (score 0):

If you put the matrices in a list, like [SteveM says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530813/lp-transport-i-want-to-prcess-alot-of-cost-matrices/77532542#comment136684317_77530813), you can write two auxiliary functions to make the code cleaner.
Below is a function that takes a list as input and calls `lp.transport` on the list's members. The list is created by a second function, `as_lptransport`.

The problems data come from the help page [`?lp.transport`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/lpSolve/html/lp.transport.html) and from the link given below.

```r
library(lpSolve)

SolveTransport <- function(object, ...) {
  with(
    object, 
    lp.transport(cost.mat, direction="min", row.signs, row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs)
  )
}

as_lptransport <- function(x, direction="min", row.signs, row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs, ...) {
  y <- list(
    cost.mat = x,
    direction = direction,
    row.signs = row.signs, row.rhs = row.rhs,
    col.signs = col.signs, col.rhs = col.rhs
  )
  class(y) <- c("lptransport", "list")
  y
}

# first create the transport problems objects
problm1 <- as_lptransport(costs, "min", row.signs, row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs)
problm2 <- as_lptransport(costs2, "min", row.signs2, row.rhs2, col.signs2, col.rhs2)

# now put the problems on a list
problems <- list(problm1, problm2)
# and call the function above on each problem
lapply(problems, SolveTransport)
#> [[1]]
#> Success: the objective function is 7790 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Success: the objective function is 2850
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
costs <- matrix (10000, 8, 5); costs[4,1] <- costs[-4,5] <- 0
costs[1,2] <- costs[2,3] <- costs[3,4] <- 7; costs[1,3] <- costs[2,4] <- 7.7
costs[5,1] <- costs[7,3] <- 8; costs[1,4] <- 8.4; costs[6,2] <- 9
costs[8,4] <- 10; costs[4,2:4] <- c(.7, 1.4, 2.1)
row.signs <- rep ("<", 8)
row.rhs <- c(200, 300, 350, 200, 100, 50, 100, 150)
col.signs <- rep (">", 5)
col.rhs <- c(250, 100, 400, 500, 200)

# from:
# https://www.acsce.edu.in/acsce/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/1585041316993_Module-4.pdf
costs2 <- matrix(
  c(3, 1, 7, 4,
    2, 6, 5, 9,
    8, 3, 3, 2),
  byrow = TRUE,
  nrow = 3L, ncol = 4L
)
row.signs2 <- rep ("<", 3)
row.rhs2 <- c(300, 400, 500)
col.signs2 <- rep (">", 4)
col.rhs2 <- c(250, 350, 400, 200)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I also tried taking my 14x8x1000 matrices ,I converted them to a vector, then I used array to convert to a 3d array 14x8x1000 called it cost.m and when calling lptransport i used format lp.transport(cost.mat=cost.m[,,i] where i can be 1 to 1000 so seems to work

Comment: Thanks all for comments really helpful

Comment: @adrian The main problem I'm seeing with my code is that you will have to repeat the constraints vectors. It's not clear from the question whether they are always the same though different matrices suggest they are.

Comment: Hi Yes they are the same for me, I am just varying the cost variable based on original cost matrix multipled by a 1000 random numbers between 0.75 and 2.0

Comment: @adrian With that new information it seems that the problem can be greatly simplified. Can you edit the question with a small working data example? Say, instead of 1000 matrices only 2 or 3.